# Initialize Scene in cocos2d with Parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to initialize a scene in cocos2d (version 0.99.5) and want to pass in a parameter. In this case, the parameter is an int value corresponding to the level number. The scene class itself is a subclass of `CCLayer`, and I'm initializing it with the node class method:

```
GameScene *scene = [GameScene node];  //GameScene subclass of CCLayer
```

I have a custom init method that takes the variable "level", as follows:

```
- (id) initWithGameLevel:(int)level {
    if ((self = [super init])){
        // etc 
    }
}
```

Just wondering: am I way off base in my approach in creating my own initWithX method, and how I would initialize the scene with the level integer?

Comment: Suggestion Jim if it is a sub class of CCLayer then your class name should be GameLayer as GameScene  looks like as a subclass of CCScene

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add this method to your subclass

```
+(id)nodeWithGameLevel:(int)level{
    return  [[[self alloc] initWithGameLevel:level] autorelease];
}
```

and instead of

```
GameScene *scene = [GameScene node];
```

write

```
GameScene *scene = [GameScene nodeWithGameLevel:levelNumber];
```

Comment: It's a thing of beauty. I realize this is something pretty basic in Objective-C. Still not sure what's happening, but this answer is a good breadcrumb for me to follow. Thanks, Inder.

Comment: @JimMcGaw, Inder is adding a class method using the expected "node" Cocos2d convention, but patterned after designated and default initializers. For your next "breadcrumb"... ;)